# Hiding table rows by toggling by default

Tags: javascript

I have a table with 5 rows. I have created toggling function that hide table. By default, table's rows are showing, and I do not want to show table rows by default. I want to hide them first. How can I do that? Below is the code:

```
function TR_set_toggle() {
    /* toggleRow method */

    var toggleRow = function()
    {
        this.style.display = ((this.style.display == '') ? 'none' : '');
        return false;
    }

    for (var oTable, a = 0; a < arguments.length; ++a)
    {
        oTable = document.getElementById(arguments[a]);
            var r = 0, row, rows = oTable.rows;
            while (row = rows.item(r++))
            row.toggle = toggleRow;
    }

    /* convenience function */
    self.toggleRow = function(row_id) {
        document.getElementById(row_id).toggle();
    } 


onload = function() {
    TR_set_toggle('foo');
}
```

Comment: Could you show your HTML as well? And, if possible, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo reproducing your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css property 'display' in your stylesheet,like this

```
td {
    display:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to call in the onload function:

toggleRow('foo1');

Where foo1 is your row_id.